# Can libreoffice differentiate between .txt and .csv files?

Tags: csv, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-writer, mime-types

Can libreoffice differentiate between .txt and .csv files?
I have two file's that have a mime type of 'plain text document' text/plain detected.
One file ends in .txt and the other ends in .csv.
Is it possible to tell libreoffice to open .txt files with writer and .csv files with calc?
Thanks

Edit on a Linux OS if I create two test files text.txt and test.csv the mimetype command does identify the files correctly:

`mimetype test.txt  test.txt: text/plain`

`mimetype test.csv  test.csv: text/csv`

and xdg-mime query filetype also returns the same thing.
Then I open the .csv file it opens calc
next when I open the .txt file from the file open dialogue it treats it as a .csv file and wants to import it.

Comment: It might be OS dependent. Windows uses extension to ostensibly identify file type, some others don't.

Comment: Thanks I am supporting Libreoffice on Linux, Windows and Mac, but I'll add Linux to this question as its mainly Linux based users.

Comment: TXT files isn't "native" to Excel nor LO-Calc. What would you expect to happen for those files, other than attempting to import it as if it was a CSV? Now, this is "not a question" - the intention is to get you `thinking`...

Comment: @Hannu thanks for your comment if the user is editing a spreadsheet and wants to open a text document libreoffice opens the text document with writer. Same if your in writer and open a spreadsheet it opens it in calc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer at present is not without applying a patch as [Its a old bug in libreoffice](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=89683)  , which some developers consider a feature.